# Learning Ruby to use serverside to manage an existing database

Tags: sql, ruby, apache-flex

I am very much a beginner to rails and I have a specific need for it. I wish to connect it to a flex app, and also use it to call a database.

For example when the following web page is visited:
?User=bob&id=4&lic=234
Take 'bob' and 4 and add them to an existing database table if the license number is valid and not already used. I don't want to use the standard database stuff, I will need to write my own SQL queries as well as have logic for checking other stuff to do with registering users etc.
It is already done with Coldfusion but I am having issues with it, and would like to have it work with Ruby instead.

But to start with, I just want the ability to call a web page (on localhost:3000) get the string after the URL "?User=bob&id=4&lic=234" in this case and output "User:bob id:4" to the screen. I want to learn what the code is doing rather than have the least lines of code solution. I would rather use as little of the rails framework to do this as this will help me learn the language. I won't be making the standard website so learning the rails framework won't be so useful to me.

Thanks for the comments, sinatra seems to be what I'm looking for, however I am having problems connecting with databases, mysql in this case:

I'm following this:
http://community.active.com/blogs/productdev/2011/02/28/using-activerecord-3-without-rails

Trying to use a Mysql database in this instance. 
However I get this error:
LoadError: Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. - F:/Software/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/1.9/mysql_api.so)

So I tried: 
gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter
However:
gem could not be found
So I did:
install instead activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter-1.2.2
However it still didn't work.

When this is working, how do you make arbitrary SQL calls?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but maybe you should check out [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) if you aren't interested in all of the 'extras' that Rails provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) or [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) and combine it with [Active record](http://community.active.com/blogs/productdev/2011/02/28/using-activerecord-3-without-rails). Using Active Record to handle your database and models is far superior to doing it all by yourself.

If you insist on doing it by yourself. You can use the [mysql2 gem](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) or [postgresql gem](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/wiki/Home) directly

Comment: Thanks, Sinatra seems suited, I got a simple app to work. Now I will look into Active Record

Comment: (how do you enter a newline in the comment? it just posts it when I hit enter) I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database this time, http://community.active.com/blogs/productdev/2011/02/28/using-activerecord-3-without-rails but am getting an error LoadError: Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. - F:/Software/RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/1.9/mysql_api.so) however when I do gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter it says its not found